# Write a query that always takes latest date partition to provide results without using max() aggregate function

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a table in SparkServer that looks like this:

```
--------------------------------------
OrderID  OrderDate  OrderNum  Date
--------------------------------------
121      1/1/2018   A1        1/3/2018
122      1/2/2018   A2        1/3/2018
121      1/1/2018   A1        1/4/2018
122      1/2/2018   A2        1/4/2018
123      1/4/2018   A3        1/4/2018
```

Now if you closely look at the data, you will notice that each **Date** partition has all of historical records plus the new records that came on that date.

Now what I'd like to do is write a query that always extracts the records from latest Date partition without using max(Date) function or hardcoding the **Date='1/4/2018'** in WHERE clause. I want to avoid aggregate function such as max(Date) due to performance issue and I can not hardcode Date partition value because I'd like this query to automatically fetch the records to refresh a dashboard.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could JOIN the table with themself and take only that records where the field `Data` has no other record major than it.

That is the records that hasn't joined record on condition `tab.Date > tab.Date`.

Let me clarify with SQL:

Here my `test_table` structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (
  `OrderID` INT NULL,
  `OrderDate` DATE NULL,
  `OrderNum` VARCHAR(2) NULL,
  `Date` DATE NULL);
```

Then I've inserted the rows as you show in the question:

```
insert into test_table values (121, '2018/01/01', 'A1', '2018/03/01');
insert into test_table values (122, '2018/02/01', 'A2', '2018/03/01');
insert into test_table values (121, '2018/01/01', 'A1', '2018/04/01');
insert into test_table values (122, '2018/02/01', 'A2', '2018/04/01');
insert into test_table values (123, '2018/04/01', 'A3', '2018/04/01');
```

Finally, the query is:

```
SELECT lastRecords.*, latestDatePartition.*
FROM test_table AS lastRecords
LEFT OUTER JOIN test_table AS latestDatePartition 
ON latestDatePartition.Date > lastRecords.Date
WHERE latestDatePartition.Date IS NULL;
```

I hope it was clear, bye.